# Flow type error on Immutable-js Record [1] is not a polymorphic type

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, immutable.js

I am using immutable-js in reactjs, when I use flow for type checking, I am getting following error.

Cannot instantiate Record because class Record [1] is not a polymorphic type.

```
 src/service/login.js
   32│
   35│ const StoreRecord: Record<LoginTypeDef> = Record({
   36│   userId: fromJS(academicYearInitialState),
   37│   userName: null,
   38│   userRole: null,
 node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow
```

[1] 1395│ declare class Record {

Following is my Record initialization.

const StoreRecord: Record = Record({
   userId: null,
   userName: null,
   userRole: null
});

LoginTypeDef is exported as,
export type LoginTypeDef = {|
  userId: string,
  userName: string,
  userRole: string
|};

Answer (score 0):

For adding annotation for the described value type `RecordFactory` should be used. It can be imported from the `immutable`.

It's usage suppose to look like:

```js
const StoreRecord: RecordFactory<LoginTypeDef> = Record({
  userId: null,
  userName: null,
  userRole: null
});
```

If needed to assign the result of the `Record` call to the variable and provide annotation for it, another type `RecordOf` should be used as following:

```js
const StoreState: RecordOf<LoginTypeDef> = StoreRecord({userId: 'test});
```